# Converting an Armadillo Matrix to an Eigen MatriXd and vice versa

Tags: eigen, rcpp, armadillo

How can I convert from an Armadillo Matrix to an Eigen MatrixXd and vice versa?

I have `nu` as an `arma::vec` of size `N`, `z` as `arma::mat` of dimension `N x 3`. I want to compute a matrix `P` such as the entry `P_ij` is

```
Pij=exp(nu(i) + nu(j) + z.row(j)*z.row(j)))
```

Thus I used this code

```
int N=z.n_rows;
mat P= exp(nu*ones(1,N) + one(N,1)*(nu.t()) + z*(z.t()));
```

But the computation takes too long. In particular, for `N = 50,000` the run time is far to high.

It seems that using Eigen can be faster. But my matrix are Armadillo. How can I use Eigen operations ? Or how can I do this operation faster.

Comment: To speed up matrix multiplication within Armadillo, link with [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) instead of standard BLAS. This makes a massive difference. Also, your code is using the `exp()` function, which can be time consuming. You can speed it up by [enabling](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) OpenMP in Armadillo.

Comment: Tanks 
I am not very beginner here. Please can you give a simple example ?

Comment: Read through the `README.txt` file that comes with the Armadillo archive ([download](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) page).  See also the Armadillo [FAQ](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)'s [`.memptr()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#memptr) class member function, we are able to extract the memory pointer. From here, we can use [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org)'s [`Map<T>()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) constructor to create an [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org) matrix.

Now, we can go from the [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) matrix using the [`.data()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) member function to extract a point to [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org)'s memory structure. Then, using the [advanced constructor options of `arma::mat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) we can create an [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) [matrix](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat).

For example:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::MatrixXd example_cast_eigen(arma::mat arma_A) {

  Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_B = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(arma_A.memptr(),
                                                        arma_A.n_rows,
                                                        arma_A.n_cols);

  return eigen_B;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat example_cast_arma(Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_A) {

  arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                               false, false);

  return arma_B;
}

/***R
(x = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
example_cast_eigen(x)
example_cast_arma(x)
*/
```

Results:

```
(x = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

example_cast_eigen(x)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

example_cast_arma(x)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

One quick remark: If you are using Eigen's Mapping function, then you should automatically have the change in the Armadillo matrix (and vice versa), e.g.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void map_update(Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_A) {

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Eigen Matrix on Entry: " << std::endl << eigen_A << std::endl;

  arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                               false, false);

  arma_B(0, 0) = 10;
  arma_B(1, 1) = 20;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Armadill Matrix after modification: " << std::endl << arma_B << std::endl;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Eigen Matrix after modification: " << std::endl << eigen_A << std::endl;
}
```

Run:

```
map_update(x)
```

Output:

```
Eigen Matrix on Entry: 
1 3
2 4

Armadill Matrix after modification: 
   10.0000    3.0000
    2.0000   20.0000

Eigen Matrix after modification: 
10  3
 2 20
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you
And how can I convert Eigen to Armadillo

Comment: Not a bad Q and a nice A.  Addition to Gallery, maybe?

Comment: Aye. Probably this weekend with the 3x other posts I need to migrate...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I'm here because a reference in R-SIG-Mac to coatless's blog posting describing how to make make an openMP-aware version of R. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/

Comment: @42 If I were you I'd use the rcpp-devel mailing list

Comment: OK. I'll subscribe. BTW, what's the Gallery? (Or perhaps this is already in the listinfo for rcpp-devel and I will see it in a couple of minutes?)

Comment: It the widely-referenced contrubuted site [over here](http://gallery.rcpp.org) with its source [here at GH](https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-gallery).

Comment: I'll admit that I probably should have googled it rather than question-commenting. First hit on the obvious strategy. So in penance, I'll now buy your book.

Comment: @coatless Thank you once for your answer. 
Your remark is very important If I intend to update the converted matrix. I found that if I do not want the update affects the first matrix, I can use arma(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, true, false) instead of  arma(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, false, false). But that is for  converting from Eigen to Armadillo. Do you know a way to convert from Armadillo to Eigen and allow update without changing Armadillo matrix?

Comment: @coatless I'm having an issue with this. The first element -i.e. at (0,0)- of the conversion from Eigen to Armadillo does not get converted correctly. I'm not sure whether I should post a new question though.

Comment: @mkln Just re-ran above and everything worked. Double check your compilation settings, package and R versions.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7AgTHPNf here's what I get. from R I also get it to work correctly

Comment: Your code is creating a new copy on call instead of using a reference on call. Need to do a reference update. This is a separate question.

Comment: That is, you need to use `arma::mat matrixxd_to_armamat(Eigen::MatrixXd& eigen_A)`.

Comment: @coatless I'll post a question, I get the same result even if I use the reference

Comment: @coatless here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176022/converting-eigenmatrixxd-to-armamat

Answer (score 4):

I just spend a couple of hours trying to convert Eigen sparse matrix to Armadillo sparse matrix and I'll post the code here if someone else find a need to do the same.

I was doing this because I could not find an eigensolver for the sparse complex matrices, and Armadillo was the only one that had it, but the rest of my code was already done in Eigen so I had to do the conversion.

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
int main() {
    auto matrixA = new SparseMatrix<complex<double>>(numCols, numRows); //your Eigen matrix

    /*
    SOME CODE TO FILL THE Eeigen MATRIX

    */
    //  now create a separate vectors for row indeces, first non-zero column element indeces and non-zero values
    //  why long long unsigned int, because armadilo will expect that type when constructing sparse matrix
    vector<long long unsigned int> rowind_vect((*matrixA).innerIndexPtr(),
                                               (*matrixA).innerIndexPtr() + (*matrixA).nonZeros());
    vector<long long unsigned int> colptr_vect((*matrixA).outerIndexPtr(),
                                               (*matrixA).outerIndexPtr() + (*matrixA).outerSize() + 1);
    vector<complex<double>> values_vect((*matrixA).valuePtr(),
                                        (*matrixA).valuePtr() + (*matrixA).nonZeros());

    //  you can delete the original matrixA to free up space
    delete matrixA;

    //new Armadillo vectors from std::vector, we set the flag copy_aux_mem=false, so we don't copy the values again
    cx_dvec values(values_vect.data(), values_vect.size(), false);
    uvec rowind(rowind_vect.data(), rowind_vect.size(), false);
    uvec colptr(colptr_vect.data(), colptr_vect.size(), false);

    //  now create Armadillo matrix from these vectors
    sp_cx_dmat arma_hamiltonian(rowind, colptr, values, numCols, numRows);

    //  you can delete the vectors here if you like to free up the space

    return 0; 

}
```