# Converting Eigen::MatrixXd to arma::mat and make a copy on a new object

Tags: c++, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I have a function within which I want to convert an `Eigen::MatrixXd` object to `arma::mat`.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700560/converting-an-armadillo-matrix-to-an-eigen-matrixd-and-vice-versa/46700774) but I can't seem to be able to correct the behavior that I'm getting. Calling `matrixxd_to_armamat` from R would cause no issues, the problem is when I have this conversion in another function in C. This is a little confusing and I would like to understand what's going on.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace std;

arma::mat matrixxd_to_armamat(Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_A) {
  arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                               false, false);
  return arma_B;
}

arma::mat matrixxd_to_armamat2(Eigen::MatrixXd& eigen_A) {
  arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                               false, false);
  return arma_B;
}



//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat tester(){
  Eigen::MatrixXd A_eigen(2,2);
  A_eigen(0,0) = 1.0;
  A_eigen(1,0) = 2.0;
  A_eigen(0,1) = -1.0;
  A_eigen(1,1) = -2.0;

  Rcpp::Rcout << A_eigen << endl;

  arma::mat A_arma  = matrixxd_to_armamat(A_eigen);
  arma::mat A_arma2 = matrixxd_to_armamat2(A_eigen);

  Rcpp::Rcout << A_arma << endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << A_arma2 << endl;

  return A_arma2;
}
/* In R
> tester()
 1 -1
 2 -2
  4.6503e-310  -1.0000e+00
  4.9407e-324   7.2661e-43

   1.0000  -1.0000
   2.0000  -2.0000

              [,1] [,2]
[1,] 4.650273e-310   -1
[2,]  2.000000e+00   -2
*/
```

Comment: @coatless here! :) and thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after running this, I can only produce a problem with `A_arma` object creation. The object here is getting an odd value indicating that the memory mapping was bad. My thought on this is because it is being copied into the function instead of a reference update. The original answer showed the manipulation under a scoped function that allowed the reference and memory re-use.

In particular, from the [`armadillo` docs on advanced ctors](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat):

> Create a matrix using data from writable auxiliary (external) memory, where ptr_aux_mem is a pointer to the memory. By default the matrix allocates its own memory and copies data from the auxiliary memory (for safety). **However, if copy_aux_mem is set to false, the matrix will instead directly use the auxiliary memory (ie. no copying); this is faster, but can be dangerous unless you know what you are doing!**

The latter part is my emphasis.

So, here under a pass-by-copy paradigm, the object needs to be fully copied vs. a reference update if writing a common cast function.

```cpp
arma::mat matrixxd_to_armamat(Eigen::MatrixXd eigen_A) {
    arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                                 true,   // changed from false to true.
                                 false); 
    return arma_B;
}
```

Now, if you are okay with linking back to the original `Eigen` object through a reference, then this should work:

```cpp
arma::mat matrixxd_to_armamat2(Eigen::MatrixXd& eigen_A) {
    arma::mat arma_B = arma::mat(eigen_A.data(), eigen_A.rows(), eigen_A.cols(),
                                 false, false);
    return arma_B;
}
```

Running both yields:

```
tester()
# 1 -1
# 2 -2
#   1.0000  -1.0000
#   2.0000  -2.0000
#
#   1.0000  -1.0000
#   2.0000  -2.0000
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   -1
#[2,]    2   -2
```

Comment: Nicely done. My first guess was also on premature optimization by misuing the constructor on a non-SEXP data but you made it a nice worked example.